# Python to JSON Serialization

Tags: python, json, serialization

I'm using the following code to serialize my Python code to JSON:

```
def toJson(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__, indent=4)
```

However, I'm trying to sort out the elements in `obj.__dict__` that equal `None`.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: When you say 'sort out' do you mean remove from the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_dict = dict([(attr,self.__dict__[attr]) for attr in self.__dict__ if self.__dict__[attr]])
return json.dumps(new_dict, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__, indent=4)
```

should do it

Comment: Joran, thanks very much - works like a charm. I marked your answer as the solution.